# How to type anything with xdotool?

Tags: x11, xdotool

I have some input field of printable ASCII characters, excluding whitespace, that I'd like to pass to `xdotool` to type as if typed by keyboard.

My attempts:

- `echo "type lol lol" | xdotool -` eats the space in the middle, so it types `lollol` instead of `lol lol`.
- `echo "type 'lol lol'" | xdotool -` correctly types `lol lol`, but it cannot type `'` in the middle.  I.e. `echo "type 'lol ' lol'" | xdotool -` doesn't type `lol ' lol`, but rather types `lol lol'`.

My question:

- How to use `xdotool` to let it type arbitrary characters without the problem above?
- In case `xdotool` is not adequate, got any alternative tool that work better?

**Update:** reason I care about this is because I'm using it for a password manager that I'm implementing.  I think it's better to type passwords by means of keyboard typing emulation, as opposed to copying-pasting via some shared clipboard, which other processes may look into to steal passwords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not understand why you have to `echo` the command via `stdin`, you can use the command directly. The following works for me (tested using `xev`):

```
$ xdotool search Event
Defaulting to search window name, class, and classname
37748737
$ xdotool type --window 37748737 "'"
$ xdotool type --window 37748737 " "
```

If you insist on passing the command via `stdin`, then apparently `xdotool` does its own parsing, so you have to escape double quotes:

```
$ echo "type --window 37748737 \"' \"" | xdotool -
```

For finer control, you can also use `key` with keysyms separated by space:

```
$ xdotool key --window 37748737 space a apostrophe
```

This is usually enough for any kind of automation you want. Note that `xdotool` simulates **key presses and releases**, not **characters**.

You have not described your use case (please edit your question and do so, and also read about the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)), but if for some reason you want paste variable text from some other source into some application, consider using the clipboard (via `xclip`), and simulating a paste action with `xdotool` in the input field - this will be much more reliable than trying to translate arbitrary text into appropriate key presses.

Comment: I'm using this for a password manager.  Not storing passwords in clipboards seems better security wise.  Passwords could be generated automatically, containing various symbols, hence the requirement of passing arbitrary characters to `xdotool`.

Comment: Note that the X "clipboard" isn't really a clipboard, it's a communication protocol between applications. If your password manager is an X application, make it take the primary selection, then the password will never be "stored in a clipboard" and your password manager can verify that the paste request is coming from the right application. And while you are at that, you can also implement what `xdotool` does to trigger the paste. This will need some old-fashioned C programming skills, and knowledge of the X libraries.

Comment: That said, trying to move arbitrary symbols (including UTF-8 ...) to a password input field by simulating key presses is going to fail for more complicated symbols - you have no idea in general what keys the underlying UI of the password manager will need for some symbols. So the X selection ("clipboard") protocol is the way to go. (Please also read up on [XY questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you should have mentioned "I want to write a password manager" as the first thing in your question).